# Java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: create In mapped drive

Tags: java, request, http-post

I created a Java application that sends an HTTP POST request to another server.

- The firewall in the server is off.
- The firewall in the PC is off.

The application works perfectly on the PC in the C drive.

The application works perfectly on the PC with a local mapping drive.

But, when I put my application in a network mapping drive, I get an error:

> java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: create in mapped drive

This is my code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(getUrl());
postRequest.setHeader(AUTHERIZTION, getAuthString());

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

This is the full error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: create
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at rest.RestClient.postGetQuery(RestClient.java:105)
    at frame.ScanJFrame.initProperty(ScanJFrame.java:195)
    at Main.runAction(Main.java:63)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

I tried this:

```
setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

But, nothing changed.

What can I do?

Comment: There is an open bug related to your question: [Socket Exception from bind to localhost if JVM installed on a share](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068568)

Comment: this may be related to network issue you can use packet tracer to identify where your error occurs

Comment: There appears to be a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35774170/3080094) for the bug that Vusal mentioned. You could test the workaround to see if the bug is related to your issue.

Comment: Could you please write your ALL command Line  to run this APPLICATION ?

Comment: //computername is a thought , file:// is also. Other subtleties with http networking include port number of the server you are calling 8080 or 80 if it is an http server, if not then it is file protocol.

Comment: Lene get this straight! The "app" is the one on another drive!?   If so then its original conf file probably contains "local settings"  not "mapped drive settings" inside for paths! Or is there something reciprocal in how it gains it's configuration across machines?

Answer (score 0):

Hazard a guess, the server has no binding to a port to listen for network external machine connections in either it's own configuration files or to its machine port in its OS configuration "network settings" the external calling PC is using, that and with http it should simply be a domain http url called.

*I best also point that the jdk or jre have a "jconsole" program in their /bin directories can be used to set up network connections for the binaries running the caller JVM.
This appears To be the problem, your java client program needs a binding to a port to the other machine to connect to it.*

If you are calling a file from another machine , use mapped drive syntax of "file://"+"//servername/afolder/file.txt"
This scheme is for url's that are mapped drives.

Answer (score 0):

I had one Socket Exception whan using apache cxf, when it calls ClientImpl but somehow because of Proxy it couldnt pass the value to autenticate.. I started to read it directilly from applicattion.properties using ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue('foo.foo', string.class);